# How do I keep my local settings file from uploading to Github whilst maintaining a sample?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, config, vscode-git

I'm using VS Code to manage my project and sync with GitHub.

In my config file, I have some API keys and endpoints which I do not want to make public, yet, I would like to maintain a version of the same file with dummy values in the project on GitHub.

As my project is essentially a bunch of scripts (not compiled), I'm unsure of the best way to manage 2 files with the same name, locally and remotely. So far I've been ignoring a backup file and I need to manually juggle every time I commit, which is fraught with danger.

Unfortunately `.gitignore` does not solve my problem because VS Code (git) identifies the local file as different to the remote file and therefore not ignorable. Then it hangs around in my modified files list, like a bad smell.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just suggest to not have the template and actual file have the same name / path in the git repo. You could name the template file something that indicates that it's a template, or put it in a directory for template files, etc.

Comment: Hmmm... I could have some sort of a first run script which copies the template to the correct location (if not exist), I guess. Or just make it a part of the manual installation steps.